# How to write regular expression results to CSV?

Tags: python-3.x, csv, python-re

I can see the results that I'm looking for in the Command Prompt, but I'm having trouble saving them to a CSV. The saved file is the location of the text and not the actual text.

```
import re, requests, csv

data = requests.get('http://www.spk-wc.usace.army.mil/fcgi-bin/getplottext.py?archive=true&plot=isbqr&length=wy&interval=d&wy=1995').text

pattern = re.compile(r'\d*\.00')

matches = pattern.finditer(data)

with open('1995.csv', 'w') as new_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(new_file)
    for success in matches:
        export = [matches]
        csv_writer.writerow(export)
```

Comment: Is that a typo, `export = [matches]`? Should be `export = [success]`, no? BTW welcome to SO! Check out the [tour] and [ask] for advice.

Comment: Oh that's great! What a dumb typo. Thank you. To pull out the string, would running a string split on it be a good way to go?

Comment: sorry meant slice not split

Comment: np. Not sure what you mean though about slicing. `success` is a string, right? How would you want to slice it?

Comment: So what it's spitting out is that fifth column from that URL, which is what I want, however each row looks like this: "<re.Match object; span=(3118, 3124), match='311.00'>" All I'm looking for is that '311' so I was thinking I could splice the string to pull it out.

Comment: OK. You could do it that way but since you're already using regex it's easier to do a group: `r'(\d*)\.00'` then pull it out with `success.group(1)`